# Spark get stdout and stderr with REST api

Tags: apache-spark

I execute Spark jobs with Spark REST API, how can I get the `stdout` and `stderr` of each Spark job?

I read the documentation [Monitoring and Instrumentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html).

The `application` API worked well, which responded:

```
[ {
  "id" : "app-20190308150153-0039",
  "name" : "Spark shell",
  "attempts" : [ {
    "startTime" : "2019-03-08T15:01:52.759GMT",
    "endTime" : "1969-12-31T23:59:59.999GMT",
    "lastUpdated" : "2019-03-08T15:01:52.759GMT",
    "duration" : 0,
    "sparkUser" : "root",
    "completed" : false,
    "appSparkVersion" : "2.3.1",
    "lastUpdatedEpoch" : 1552057312759,
    "startTimeEpoch" : 1552057312759,
    "endTimeEpoch" : -1
  } ]
} ]
```

So I tried `/applications/[base-app-id]/logs` API like:

```
wget localhost:4040/api/v1/applications/app-20190308150153-0039/logs
```

but got a confusing response. The response is

```
PK
```

What's `PK`? How to get the correct response?